# Как создать DialogFragment со своей разметкой

Tags: android, dialogfragment

Здравствуйте!
Пишу учебную программу таймер. И хочу через диалоговое окно задавать время для таймер (минуты, секунды). Читал официальную документацию, но не получается сделать так как хочется. Можно ли стандартным способом задавать минуты и секунды, а не часы и минуты? 
Я создал свою разметку для диалог фрагмета с двумя NumberPicker

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPickerMin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPickerSec"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

И создал класс DialogFragment

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;


public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

// Объявил переменный для работы с пикерами и View, который потом подключу к AlertDialog
private NumberPicker mNumberPickerMin;
private NumberPicker mNumberPickerSec;
private View mView;

// Выполнил все необходимые действия с пикерами в onCreateView
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_set_timer, null);

    mNumberPickerMin = (NumberPicker)mView.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerMin);
    mNumberPickerSec = (NumberPicker)mView.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerSec);

    mNumberPickerMin.setMaxValue(60);
    mNumberPickerMin.setMinValue(0);
    mNumberPickerMin.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
    mNumberPickerSec.setMaxValue(60);
    mNumberPickerSec.setMinValue(0);
    mNumberPickerMin.setOnValueChangedListener(this);


    return mView;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Временно закомментировал строку
    //LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setTitle("Set time")
            // Передаю в метод setView() созданный объект mView, в котором 
            // сделал все необходимые действия с пикерами
            .setView(mView)
            .setPositiveButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // код для передачи данных
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
    }
}

@Override
public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
    // код для пикеров
}
```

Проект запускается в эмуляторе, но при вызове диалога программа закрывается с ошибкой:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.grina.dialogfragment2, PID: 2026
             android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Window feature must be requested before adding content
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.throwFeatureRequestIfSubDecorInstalled(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1636)
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.requestWindowFeature(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:546)
             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.supportRequestWindowFeature(AppCompatDialog.java:127)
             at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:211)
             at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:240)
             at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
             at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
             at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:406)
             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1986)
             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1102)
             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
             at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Может нужно просто работать с классом диалог фрагмента как с фрагментом просто наследуя класс от DialogFragment? Я так пробовал, но тогда пропадают кнопки диалогового окна, а свои кнопки выглядят некрасиво. В общем буду очень благодарен, если кто поможет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось как всегда просто)) знать бы это заранее)) Надо добавить все необходимые действия с пикерами в onCreateDialog() Просто когда читал в нете как это делать, на глаза попалась статься, в которой говорилось что нужен метод onCreateView(). А эти два метода, onCreateView() и onCreateDialog(), не желательно использовать вместе. Из-за того что они были у меня оба, шел конфликт и программа не работала. Стоило убрать первый и все заработало.

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;


public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

private NumberPicker mNumberPickerMin;
private NumberPicker mNumberPickerSec;     

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // Создаем LayoutInflater 
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    // И с его помощью создаем наше view, которое потом и передадим в метод setView()
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment.xml, null);

    // Далее в нашем view делаем все необходимое с элементами в разметке

    mNumberPickerMin = (NumberPicker)mView.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerMin);
    mNumberPickerSec = (NumberPicker)mView.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerSec);

    mNumberPickerMin.setMaxValue(60);
    mNumberPickerMin.setMinValue(0);
    mNumberPickerMin.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
    mNumberPickerSec.setMaxValue(60);
    mNumberPickerSec.setMinValue(0);
    mNumberPickerMin.setOnValueChangedListener(this);

    // и дальше все как обычно, создаем наш DialogFragment и в метод setView()
    // передаем созданное вью с "настроенными" элементами на разметке
    builder.setTitle("Set time")
            .setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // код для передачи данных
                    dialog.cancel();
            }
        })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    return builder.create();
    }
}

@Override
public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
    // код для пикеров
}
```

Answer (score 2):

По поводу запуска из фрагмента. Не совсем понятно в чем проблема с `getActivity()`. Если вы пытаетесь свой код запустить в конструкторе фрагмента, то это неверно. Нужно создавать `MyDialogFragment` по запросу пользователя (клик или что угодно). Тогда и `getActivity()` вернет то что надо и все создастся как надо.

По инициализации пикеров. Создавайте контент диалога отдельно и инициализируйте его, потом вставляйте в диалог. Как-то так:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_set_timer, null);
NumberPicker picker1 = (NumberPicker)v.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerMin);
// второй точно так же
// завайте им значения, вешайте листенеры...

builder.setTitle("Set time")
        .setView(v)
        ...
```

Comment: То есть в классе диалога выполнить вне метода onCreateDialog все необходимые действия и затем созданный объект View подключить к AlertDialog? А весь код с NumberPicker может надо писать в обычном фрагментовском onCreateView?

Comment: Да, можно в `onCreateView()` все создать и затем в `onCreateDialog()` просто вставить в диалог.

Comment: что-то не получается у меня сделать как вы сказали. Посмотрите пожалуйста код, я подправил его исходя из вашего совета. Сделал все необходимое с пикерами в 'onCreateView()' но чтобы объект View был виден в методе 'onCreateDialog' объявил его на уровне класса и использовал в методе 'setView()'. Выдает ошибку: Window feature must be requested before adding content. Смысл понятен, но не знаю как функцию запросить прежде чем добавлять содержимое.

Comment: А можно увидеть полный stacktrace ошибки? Не уверен что она связана напрямую с этим фрагментом.

Comment: Добавил log ошибки в описание вопроса. Кстати, с запуском диалога из фрагмента я разобрался. Теперь запускается из любого фрагмента. А вот с пикерами и своей разметкой пока не понятно.

Comment: Очень похоже на вот этот баг в Support Library: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183186

Comment: Перенесите весь код в `onCreateDialog()`, должно помочь. Если нет, попробуйте заменить `AlertDialog` на стандартный, не из support library.